# minimal Numeric.AD example won't compile

Tags: haskell, types, automatic-differentiation, autodiff

I am trying to compile the following minimal example from Numeric.AD:

```
import Numeric.AD 
timeAndGrad f l = grad f l
main = putStrLn "hi"
```

and I run into this error:

```
test.hs:3:24:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘f (Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse
                                       s a)
                                  -> Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a’
                with actual type ‘t’
      because type variable ‘s’ would escape its scope
    This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
      a type expected by the context:
        Data.Reflection.Reifies s Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Tape =>
        f (Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a)
        -> Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a
      at test.hs:3:19-26
    Relevant bindings include
      l :: f a (bound at test.hs:3:15)
      f :: t (bound at test.hs:3:13)
      timeAndGrad :: t -> f a -> f a (bound at test.hs:3:1)
    In the first argument of ‘grad’, namely ‘f’
    In the expression: grad f l
```

Any clue as to why this is happening? From looking at previous examples I gather that this is "flattening" `grad`'s type:

`grad :: (Traversable f, Num a) => (forall s. Reifies s Tape => f (Reverse s a) -> Reverse s a) -> f a -> f a`

but I actually need to do something like this in my code. In fact, this is the most minimal example that won't compile. The more complicated thing I want to do is something like this:

```
example :: SomeType
example f x args = (do stuff with the gradient and gradient "function")
    where gradient = grad f x
          gradientFn = grad f
          (other where clauses involving gradient and gradient "function")
```

Here's a slightly more complicated version with type signatures that does compile.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Numeric.AD 
import Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse

-- compiles but I can't figure out how to use it in code
grad2 :: (Show a, Num a, Floating a) => (forall s.[Reverse s a] -> Reverse s a) -> [a] -> [a]
grad2 f l = grad f l

-- compiles with the right type, but the resulting gradient is all 0s...
grad2' :: (Show a, Num a, Floating a) => ([a] -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
grad2' f l = grad f' l
       where f' = Lift . f . extractAll
       -- i've tried using the Reverse constructor with Reverse 0 _, Reverse 1 _, and Reverse 2 _, but those don't yield the correct gradient. Not sure how the modes work

extractAll :: [Reverse t a] -> [a]
extractAll xs = map extract xs
           where extract (Lift x) = x -- non-exhaustive pattern match

dist :: (Show a, Num a, Floating a) => [a] -> a
dist [x, y] = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)

-- incorrect output: [0.0, 0.0]
main = putStrLn $ show $ grad2' dist [1,2]
```

However, I can't figure out how to use the first version, `grad2`, in code because I don't know how to deal with `Reverse s a`. The second version, `grad2'`, has the right type because I use the internal constructor `Lift` to create a `Reverse s a`, but I must not be understanding how the internals (specifically the parameter `s`) works, because the output gradient is all 0s. Using the other constructor `Reverse` (not shown here) also produces the wrong gradient.

Alternatively, are there examples of libraries/code where people have used the `ad` code? I think my use case is a very common one.

Comment: What happens if you provide a type signiture to timeAndGrad? You may have more luck with the rank-1 approach, too.

Comment: I edited my question to add a type signature and another approach (which also doesn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `where f' = Lift . f . extractAll` you essentially create a back door into the automatic-differentiation underlying type that throws away all the derivatives and only keeps the constant-values. If you then use this for `grad`, it's hardly surprising that you get a zero result!

The sensible way is to just use `grad` as it is:

```
dist :: Floating a => [a] -> a
dist [x, y] = sqrt $ x^2 + y^2
-- preferrable is of course `dist = sqrt . sum . map (^2)`

main = print $ grad dist [1,2]
-- output: [0.4472135954999579,0.8944271909999159]
```

You don't really need to know anything more complicated to use automatic differentiation. As long as you only differentiate `Num` or `Floating`-polymorphic functions, everything will work as-is. If you need to differentiate a function that's passed in as an argument, you need to make that argument rank-2 polymorphic (an alternative would be to switch to the rank-1 version of the `ad` functions, but I daresay that is less elegant and doesn't really gain you much).

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, UnicodeSyntax #-}

mainWith :: (∀n . Floating n => [n] -> n) -> IO ()
mainWith f = print $ grad f [1,2]

main = mainWith dist
```

Comment: Yes, I do need to differentiate a function that's passed in as an argument. Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "make that argument rank-2 polymorphic?" I also tried switching to the rank-1 version of grad, and it requires me to specify that the function has type ([Forward a] -> Forward a).

Comment: The type does not allow a function with type (Num a => [a] -> a) as you use here, but I am able to pass that in in the code. I'm not sure why the types behave this way.